# Windows Programming - Hook the http request or the browser's messages?

Tags: windows, browser, hook, http-request

There are some websites which make me waste much time so I want to block them by writing a hook program. 
Can i do it?
Can i hook the http request of the OS or the browser's messages?

Answer (score 0):

Well... you could but that would be the complicated way.

By far the easiest mechanism for blocking a site from a single computer is to edit your hosts file and change the DNS name to resolve to your local host.

1. Start Notepad.exe as administrator
2. Open the `hosts` file in  `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`
3. at the bottom add a line like:
   `127.0.0.1   www.google.com`
4. Save the file.

If you put in the exact thing I did above then you will no longer be able to get to google from any browser on your machine.

---

If you don't want the easy way, there are 2 other approaches.

One is system wide at which point you need to create a proxy server and modify the system to point to that proxy.  Then you can decide what to do with the traffic.  This is how [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) works and is pretty much the only way to ensure you get *almost* all of the traffic.

The second is to create browser specific add-on.  IE calls it a Browser Helper Object (BHO), I think Firefox just calls it a "Browser Extension", etc.  You will have to build a separate one for each browser (IE/FF/Chrome) you want to cover.  Google those terms to see how to get started.  Beware that doing so is quite complicated and will require you to jump through a lot of hoops for security reasons.

This article is a bit old (2010) but should give you enough information to at least know what you are about to get yourself into:  https://msmvps.com/blogs/vcsjones/archive/2010/05/23/writing-a-managed-internet-explorer-extension-part-1.aspx

Comment: i know this but question is about hook. I want to do this in a programmatically way by using hook. Anyway thanks for your help